# Save file in Android: java.io.FileNotFoundException. open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Tags: java, android

I've a next problem... I searched answer on the source, but didn't find a good answer...

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mounted/EmailClient/side-corner.png: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:453)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:73) etc
```

Code:

```
private static String saveFile(String filename, InputStream input) {
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(path)) {
        try {
            byte[] attachment = new byte[input.available()];
            input.read(attachment);
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/EmailClient/", filename);
            if (!file.mkdirs())
                Log.d("EmailClient", "saveFile: Dir not created");
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file); //PROBLEM!
            out.write(attachment);
            input.close();
            out.close();
            return path;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("EmailClient", "saveFile: File not saved", e);;
        }
    }
    return path;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use this code

```
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/EmailClient/");

folder.mkdirs();
File file = new File(folder,filename);
file.createNewFile();
```

Comment: Folder and file is created, but the size of file = 0. mkdirs() and createNewFile() return false...

Comment: but according to exception, error is file not found

Comment: but byte[] attachment = [B@428943b8

Comment: @PawneshwerGupta file.mkdirs() will create directories so result will be directory not file you can write into. so FileNotFoundException

Comment: This solution isn't working with Android 10(Samsung devices). Could you please elaborate any particular change that need attention?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are trying to save the file in the "DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS"  directory,. So you should follow the below code.
The below line gives the directory.

```
   path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
        Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
```

If You want to create specific folder "Email_Client" inside that path, write this line.

```
   File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
   Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)+"/Email_Client/");
```

And you should declare the permission "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"

```
String fileName="myfile.txt";
            String input="Hello World";
            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
            File file=null;
            if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(path)) {
                try {
                    byte[] attachment = input.getBytes();

      File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
       Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)+"/Email_Client/");
       folder.mkdirs();


                         file=new File(folder,fileName);
          //Automatically creates the new empty file specified by the name,   if it is not exist.
                         file.createNewFile();
                        Log.i("EmailClient", "saveFile: Dir created");
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file); 
                    out.write(attachment);

                    out.close();


                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("EmailClient", "saveFile: File not saved", e);;
                }
            }
```

Please refer this URL:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String)

Comment: I tried this. Don't works. and I use MVP pattern and I don't use context there.

Answer (score 1):

If you are building your app with target version API level greater than 27 then the storage access disabled by default. If you want to enable it quickly, add the following line in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

```
<manifest ... >
  <application 
       android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"   //add this line 
       ... >
    ...
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Thank you Sir .It save my time

Comment: Thank you Ganesan for your valuable comment